# How to use nelmio/api-doc-bundle without symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

My web application is not based on Symfony or any other open-source framework.

How can I still use the package nelmio/api-doc-bundle to generate my API documentation from class annotations?

Comment: You need its dependencies, it depends on various Symfony components, so they'd need installed. You don't need to use them directly in your application code anywhere you don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

nelmio-api-doc bundle is made symfony platform only so you can not use it without symfony.

if you want to use only API documentation then https://swagger.io/swagger-ui/ may help you. swagger provides ymal and json (annotations is also part of symfony) based documentation and its implement most of popular work platform.

actually nelmio-api-doc bundle is using swagger-ui as API documentation provider (in config setting https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle)

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly require in the lib but since it's a Symfony bundle it will come with a lot of unnecessary bloat.

Why not try PHP Swagger? https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php

Here's the type of thing you can do with it:

```
/**
 *
 * @OA\Get(
 *     path="/oauth2/authorize",
 *     @OA\Response(response="200", description="An access token"),
 *     tags={"auth"},
 *     @OA\Parameter(
 *         name="response_type",
 *         in="query",
 *         type="string",
 *         description="the type of response",
 *         required=true,
 *         default="code"
 *     ),
 *     @OA\Parameter(
 *         name="client_id",
 *         in="query",
 *         type="string",
 *         description="the client identifier",
 *         required=true,
 *         default="testclient"
 *     ),
 *     @OA\Parameter(
 *         name="client_secret",
 *         in="query",
 *         type="string",
 *         description="the client identifier",
 *         required=false,
 *         default="testclient"
 *     ),
 *     @OA\Parameter(
 *         name="redirect_uri",
 *         in="query",
 *         type="string",
 *         description="where to send the response",
 *         required=false
 *     ),
 *     @OA\Parameter(
 *         name="state",
 *         in="query",
 *         type="string",
 *         description="with a CSRF token. This parameter is optional but highly recommended.",
 *         required=false,
 *     ),
 *     @OA\Parameter(
 *         name="scope",
 *         in="query",
 *         type="string",
 *         description="allowed scopes, space separated",
 *         required=false,
 *     )
 * )
 */
public function authorizeAction()
{
    // code
}
```

Here's a demo of what Swagger UI generates:
https://petstore.swagger.io/